# How can I keep a object in linked list node?

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, linked-list

I have a project and project wants a student management system. I started to do. Each student must have 3 properties (id,name,surname) and I have to keep a node in linked list. How can I keep that 3 properties in a node and how can I establish that connection?

Comment: Do you know the OOP basics, do you know of classes and instance that you can create? You should follow a tutorial on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about Inheritance, Generics in Java. You can do it like:

```
List<Student> students = new LinkedList<>();
students.add(new Student(1, "name1", "surname1"));
students.add(new Student(2, "name2", "surname2")); 
students.add(new Student(3, "name3", "surname3"));
```

and print them like:

```
for (Student student : students) {
    System.out.println(student);
}
```

And Student class:

```
    public static class Student {
        private long id;
        private String name;
        private String surname;

        public Student(long id, String name, String surname) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Ezgi can you accept my answer or at leas plus it :D?